# addition of one column with certain condition in another colum, like sumifs of excel in matlab

Tags: matlab, count, conditional-statements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [addition of one column with certain condition in another colum, like sumifs of excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385732/addition-of-one-column-with-certain-condition-in-another-colum-like-sumifs-of-e)

here i want to count the no of 2nd column, with the same conditions in column 1,
i m dictating here again,

A=[1 2;2 3;3 4;3 2;4 3;5 4;5 2;6 3;7 2;8 3]

now i want to count no of 2, 3 and 4 in column2, condition is that when column 1 ranges from 0 to 3, 3 to 6, 6 to 9, 9 to 12 like that.

answer is like that

ranges no2, no3, no4

0 to 3-- 2-----1-------1

3 to 6---1------2-------1

6 to 9-- --1-----1------0

help me,,,, waiting for your reply..

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do something like this:

```
for(n=1:size(A,1))
    if(A(n,1) >= 0 && A(n,1) < 3)
        % Do something
    elseif( ) % next test condition
        % Do something there.
    end 
end
```

Another option would be to use the for loop to go through your first column and using a switch statement to pull the appropriate action based on that input.

Update below:

```
for(n = 1:size(A,1))
    switch(mod(A(n,1),3))
        case 0 % this will be 0, 1, 2 in your column
            % code
        case 1
            etc...
    end
end
```

[Info on modulus in matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mod.html)

[Info on switch in matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/switch.html)

Comment: i have lot of conditions together, but their interval is constant that is 3,, so plz modify and help me..

Comment: Okay, then you should look up modulus math and apply that to your scenario.  I'll toss an example above, but you'll have to flush it out.

Comment: to Ben A. I need a program which input the condition of 0 to 3, 3 to 6 automaticaly, it is like lim=0, interval=3, then lim=lim+interval,, so plz use this information and let me know hw can i proceed

Comment: @DibyenduPal you have all the tools right there in front of you.  I can't really provide much more insight without completely solving it for you.  It'd be best if you could try and work it out, show some code you try and then people can work from there.  I also noticed this was closed as a duplicate of another posting, I looked there and was that answer not correct?

Comment: that answer is 100% correct, but here problem is little bit different, so i am not able to solve it, here two conditions are there and need to count only, earlier problem was only one conditions for 1st column, now have 1 conditions in 1st column and again need to count different no within the range/.. thnx for the advice

Answer (score 0):

With MATLAB you can use logical indexing meaning that you can filter a variable with any number of conditions. For example, if `vec` is any vector and you wish to know how many elements of `vec` are negative you can do the following,

```
% save the elements of vec which are negative
ind = vec < 0
% vec is a logical variable. Each element of vec lower that 0 is store as 1.
% to know how many elements of vec are smaller than 0
sum(ind)
% will tell you how many ones are there in ind, meaning the number of elements in vec which
% are smaller than 0

% Of course you can do the same all at once,
sum(vec < 0)
% and you can directly access the elements in the same way
vec(vec < 0)
```

So returning to your problem, you can use something like,

```
for i = 1:3:length(A)
    %print how many 2s,3s and 4s
    fprintf('%d to %d: %d, %d, %d\n',i,i+2,sum(A(i:i+2,2)==2),sum(A(i:i+2,2)==3),sum(A(i:i+2,2)==4))
end
```

Comment: as i have lot of such conditions together, so i cant put the conditions again and again, I need a program so that i can put those conditions together,, but my interval between condition is constant,, that is 3,, so plz help me

Comment: this solution is giving out put only for position of i, but here not position of i, rather than no difference, not row difference,, plz its also saying matrix exceed index dimensions